# Put small title under name in a signature

Tags: legend

I want to put a descriptive name under the name in a signature:

I currently have:

```
\def\sig#1{\vbox{\hsize=5.5cm
    \kern2cm\hrule\kern1ex
    \hbox to \hsize{\strut\hfil #1 \hfil}}}

\newcommand\signatures[4]{%
\hbox to \hsize{\hfil #1, \today\hfil}
\hbox to \hsize{\quad\sig{#2}\hfil\hfil\sig{#3}\quad}
\hbox to \hsize{}}


\signatures{Institution}{Name 1}{Name 2}{}
```

which is :

[image]

But I want:
[image]

What should be added to the code to show that?

I call it using

```
\signatures{Institution}{Name 1}{Name 2}{}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `\shortstack{}`, which allows you to use line breaks:

```
\hbox to \hsize{\quad\sig{\shortstack{#2\\[0.5ex]Advisor A}}\hfil\hfil\sig{\shortstack{#3\\[0.5ex]Advisor B}}\quad}
```

[image]

You can adjust the spacing between `Name` and `Advisor` using the optional length argument of `\\`.