# How to make text fields for signatures at the bottom of each page?

Tags: formatting, positioning, signatures

I need to make text fields for signatures at the bottom of each page.
Like this (i drew it in Adobe Illustrator):
[image: Sample text fields]

How can i do this?

Paper format: A4.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Dynamic signature/date line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48152/5764); [Signature line with dots and name below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183698/5764); [How to create a signature, date page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35942/5764); [Adding dots for signature in a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359422/5764); [Put small title under name in a signature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27925/5764); [Creating a right aligned signature block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303590/5764)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}

\SetBgContents{
\vspace*{\fill}
{\def\arraystretch{0.6}\tabcolsep=3pt
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\textbf{Tom Brand} & \makebox[1.5in]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[1.5in] & \textbf{Ryan Cruise} & \makebox[1.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
& \small \textit{(signature)} & & & \small \textit{(signature)} 
\end{tabular}
}
}

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgPosition{current page.south}
\SetBgHshift{0.8cm}
\SetBgVshift{1.3cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Signatures]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in numerous ways ([suggested references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457562/how-to-make-text-fields-for-signatures-at-the-bottom-of-each-page#comment1150937_457562)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper = a4paper,
  margin = 1in
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\signature}[2][8em]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ p{#1} p{#1} }
    \strut\raggedleft
    \raisebox{-.5ex}[0pt][0pt]{\bfseries #2} & \\
    \cline{2-2}
    & \centering\scriptsize\itshape (signature)
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\vspace{5\baselineskip}

\mbox{}\hfill
\signature{James Bond}\hfill
\signature{Austin Powers}\hfill
\mbox{}

\end{document}
```